# HTML CSS background image keeps width same size as the width of browser

Tags: html, css, image

I have background images for my website, but the background seems to keep to the same size as the browser. I will explain in photos beneath for an idea of what i'm trying to explain.

[image: This is what I want to achieve]

[image: This is not]

The top image shows the background fits the browser, whereas the second image, the background doesn't fit as the browser has been clipped to the left and has halved in size. Here, instead of adding white space between the background image, I wish for this to zoom into the image instead.

I'm not sure what could be the issue with this, thanks for the help.

```css
@import compass;
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marvel:400,400italic);
/*
html { 
  background: url(countryside.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Guldscript';
    src: url('.eot');
    src: url('guldscript.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('guldscript.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('guldscript.woff') format('woff'),
         url('guldscript.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('guldscript.svg#Bruss') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
html, body{overflow:hidden;}
h1 {
  font-family: Guldscript;
  color: #FCFFF5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-indent: 40px;

}

h2 {
  font-family: Guldscript;
  color: #FCFFF5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-indent: 40px;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #1E1E20;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.container {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 180px auto;
}

.shrink {
  padding: 0.5px 0;
}


.centered {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 70%;
  left: 70%;
  margin-top: -35%;
  margin-left: -35%;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1E1E20;
  font-family: Guldscript;
  color: #FDFDFD;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-indent: 40px;
  height:40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  z-index: 10;

}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1E1E20;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

li a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

p.maintext {
 padding-top: 100px;
 padding-left: 20%;
 padding-right: 20%;
 font-family: 'Marvel', sans-serif;
 color: white;
 background-color: 1E1E20;
 text-align: justify;
}

.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- 
 Sunday, 31st January 2016. | I got bored and made this website | v . 01
-->

<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.maximage.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="CSS" charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.maximage.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
  <title>asd</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       $(document).on("scroll", function(){
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
          $(".header").addClass("shrink");
        } else {
          $(".header").removeClass("shrink");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    $(function (){
      $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
        auto: true,
        fade: 700,
        speed: 1500,
      });

    });
  </script>

 </head>

 <body>



    <header class="header">
    <nav>
   <h1>asde</h1>
<!--
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">me</a></li>  
      <li><a href="">photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="">queries</a></li>
      <li><a href="">connect</a></li>
    </ul>
-->
    </nav>

    <!--<h2>Cardiff University</h2>-->
    </header>
 </body>
<!--      <div id="maximage">

    </div>-->
          <ul class="rslides">
      <li><img src="images/home_slideshow/Rugby.jpg" alt="Image of Judgement day, Wales."></li>
      <li><img src="images/home_slideshow/Tractor.jpg" alt="Image of our Tractor."></li>
      <li><img src="images/home_slideshow/Axe.jpg" alt="Image of an Axe."></li>
      </ul>
    <div class="footer">
    <center>asd</center>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry it's not very clear what you want to do here?

Comment: You mean it keeps resizing itself even after you comment out the `background-size:cover` bits? In that case, it sounds like a caching issue. Anyway, the snippet doesn't show anything. Try with a publicly available image.

Comment: @NathanielFlick rslides in the CSS is linked to the list within the html that has all the images listed. I believe that something within the rslides part of the CSS (at the bottom) is the reasoning for the background images not covering the entire page

Comment: If you're using RoyalSlider here's instructons on making the slider full screen: http://help.dimsemenov.com/kb/royalslider-jquery-plugin-faq/how-stretch-slider-to-full-browser-width-and-height

Answer (score 0):

You will need an element that has a width of `100vw` and a height of `100vh` (possibly `body`, but you can use any element that is positioned absolutely). Then, set the CSS property `background-image` to the image url, and `background-size` to `cover`.

Edit:
Check my minimal JSFiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/0vg9omfq/